# IBM i User Space Security

Tags: ibm-midrange

Does anyone know how secure user spaces *USRSPC are in the event of a power outage?

I use user spaces to provide last number issued on a per-file basis. I use so-called machine-code API to prevent the same number being issue twice. I have found duplicates caused by the user space not being saved to disc prior to re-IPL.

It would not appear that user spaces are eligible for journaling. Or does anyone know of a way that I could journal each time the last number issued is incremented?

Regards,
Frank Marshall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a force parameter on the [quschgus](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/quschgus.htm) API.  Set that parameter to '2' to force user space changes to be immediately written to disk.

```
             PGM

             DCL        VAR(&USRSPC) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(20)
             dcl        &start *int
             dcl        &len *int
             dcl        &data *char 2000
             dcl        &rtndata *char 2000
             dcl        &force *char 1
             dcl        &attr *char 10
             dcl        &size *int
             dcl        &init *char 1
             dcl        &pubaut *char 10
             dcl        &desc *char 50

             chgvar     &usrspc 'STEVE     QGPL'
             chgvar     &attr ' '
             chgvar     &size 2000
             chgvar     &init ' '
             chgvar     &pubaut '*ALL'
             chgvar     &desc 'user space demo'
             call       pgm(quscrtus) parm(&usrspc &attr &size &init &pubaut &desc )

             chgvar     &start 25
             chgvar     &len 10
             RTVJOBA    JOB(&DATA)
             chgvar     &force '2'
             call       quschgus parm(&usrspc &start &len &data &force )

             chgvar     &usrspc 'STEVE     QGPL'
             chgvar     &start 25
             chgvar     &len 10
             call       qusrtvus parm(&usrspc &start &len &rtndata)
             sndpgmmsg  msg('data returned:' *cat &rtndata)

             endpgm
```

Comment: Thanks RockBoro. I am sure that will do the job. I don't suppose you have any idea as to whether it degrades performance significantly?

Comment: My user space is:
8 bytes to contain an 18 digit last number issued
4 bytes to hold the increment (usually 1)
4 bytes for a yyyymmdd representation of the current date - it doesn't actually do anything. 
The user space was created with a length of 64 bytes. I am thinking of using the next 8 bytes for another number. I'll call it disc# Once my new number is issued by _CMPSWP procedure I will compare it with disc# and if it is > disc# I will add 100 * the increment and save the user space to disc using quschgus.
The objective is to only have to write it once every 100 updates. 

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

A *USRSPC seems a little of an overkill for storing sequence numbers to me. And it's persistence, as you have found is a little lacking. A *DTAARA is better as it doesn't have the auto-extension logic under the covers. Or a database SEQUENCE which is specifically made for what you are trying to use sequences for. The SEQUENCE is in fact implemented over a data area.

Comment: I didn't think that a data area was thread safe.

Comment: Where are you using threads? And there is nothing inherantly non-threadsafe about data areas, just for specific commands and in specific instances. Of course, if you are using it in an RPG program, you are almost always running single threaded anyway, so you don't have to worry about threads.